# json parse error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1009'

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm developing an application which does an Ajax call to a PHP script which returns `json_encode` data.

The data is being returned from PHP as expected. But when trying to parse it in jquery I'm getting a console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1009'

followed by a copy of my data array.

An example of the json encoded data is here:

```
[
{"u_id":"21747","fname":"Andy","lname":"","email":"foo@bar.com"},
{"u_id":"3748","fname":"John","lname":"","email":"foo@baz.com"},      
{"u_id":"451750","fname":"Peter","lname":"","email":"someone@else.com"},
]
```

The jquery I'm using is as follows. The desired output is for it to display a list of people's email addresses next to a tickbox:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(".modal-body").html("Loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= $router->pathFor('/admin/ajax/find-user'); ?>",
                data: {
                    searchInput: $('#searchInput').val()
                },
                method: "POST",
          }).done(function(data) {
             //$(".modal-body").html(data);
             $.parseJSON(data);
             $.each(data, function(key, value){
                 $(".modal-body").html('<input type="checkbox" id="' + value.u_id + '">' + value.email + "<br>");
          });
      });
    });
});
```

What's wrong with this, and what does the error mean (I can't see 1009 anywhere in my data, although not sure if that's what it actually means?)

Comment: *"I'm just showing the .done part for brevity"* Too much brevity. What is `data`? Where is it coming from? If you're loading it via `ajax` and returning it with a proper `Content-Type` header, it's probably been parsed into an array of objects, but...

Comment: Do `console.log(data);` and paste your output into question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated to show full jquery in use

Comment: @divix: Better yet, rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, use the fully-functional debugger built into the browser to turn on the lights. :-)

Comment: `$.parseJSON(data);` was at the suggestion of another commenter (below) and it makes no difference as you say. When I do `console.log(data)` it outputs the json array as given - without any errors. That was also why I had `//$(".modal-body").html(data);` in there so I could check what PHP was sending back, but it looks ok.

Comment: @Andy you need to assign the parsed JSON to the data again so do: `data = $parseJSON(data);`.

Comment: Ok, when it's been corrected to `var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);` and then I loop through `parsedData` that has solved the problem. The only issue now is that it's overwriting `.modal-body` on each iteration as mentioned by @T.J.Crowder but that's a totally different issue for me to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **parse** your JSON data first:

```
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
```

But if your PHP script returns the JSON with the correct `Content-Type`, you don't need to do that. If you ensure that the PHP script sends `Content-Type: application/json`, jQuery will automatically parse it before giving it to you. So that's another way to fix the problem.

Comment: Odds are jQuery already parsed it; too bad the OP didn't show us a bit more context.

Comment: I've updated it to show the full jquery in use and also tried @Rax's line but has made no difference

Comment: It's a cosmetic, but you don't actually need extra var, just use `data =`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the suggestion about the json header. I have amended this in my PHP script and can now implement this without `$.parseJSON(data)`. Also thank you to @divx, I have removed the redundant `var` and still works. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score -2):

Not So Sure !! 
but can You try with **largeJSONobject.data**
LIKE 
$.each(largeJSONobject.data, function(key, value){
        $(".modal-body").html('' + value.email + "
");
});